# ConstraintLayout RecyclerView displays under BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

How to get the RecyclerView not displaying under BottomNavigationView with ConstraintLayout.

Here is the result (the recycler is supposed to display 20 elements)

[image]

And here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myListSimple"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try defining `RecyclerView`s constraint bottom as top of the `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: @dgngulcan : thanx, I have already tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `match_parent` for both `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` of the `RecyclerView` which is not recommended for `Views` contained in `ConstraintLayout`. You should use `0dp` instead to match the constraints:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myListSimple"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: thanx a lot if I could I would give you all my points I have wasted a lot of time on this. Any documentation with this solution?

Comment: It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) in the Dimensions Constraints section.